# Avoid recursion in one to many relation in jpa entities

Tags: jpa, recursion, one-to-many

I have two entities paymentTransaction and paymentCard as follows. When I fetch paymentTransactions It stuck in infinite call from one to another. I have tried @JsonIgnore, @JsonIdentityInfo and etc to sortout this issue but non of them works. I'm running select query as HQL query like this

```
FROM PassengersLogArchive as pass_log INNER JOIN " +
                "PaymentTransactions as pmt_txn ON pmt_txn.tripId=pass_log.passengersLogId
```

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Table(name = "payment_transactions")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class PaymentTransactions {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "trip_id")
    private Long tripId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "card_id")
    private PaymentCards paymentCard;

}


@Data
@Table(name = "payment_cards")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class PaymentCards {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "passenger_id")
    private Long passengerId;

    @Column(name = "masked_number")
    private String maskedNumber;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "paymentCard", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions;

}
```

Comment: In what sense are you 'stuck'? Where are you seeing infinite recursion, what's the stacktrace?

Comment: It's like this when fetch payment_transaction it has to get paymentTransactions field in PaymentCard  entity, PaymentCard has paymentTransactions field it will try to get data from paymentTransaction entity so then it's a never ending loop

Comment: 'it will try to get data' is the crucial part. WHAT will try to get data? Show us the stacktrace, please

Comment: @crizzis thanks for your help I have solved this by adding ToString.Exclude annotation to paymentTransactions field in PaymentsCard Entity

Comment: Anyway stacktrace is nothing but after some time it gives stack over flow exception